# factors turn to integers when assigning in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
employee <- c("John Doe","Peter Gynn","Jolie Hope")
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
data1 <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)

employee <- c("John Doe", "Rob", "Peter Gynn", "Ellen A")
city <- c("city1", "city2", "city3", "city1")
age <- c( 1,3,4,2)
data2 <- data.frame(employee, city, age)
```

I'm trying to combine them and I encountered a following problem: Factors are turned to integers.

```
data1$city <- NA
data1$age <- NA
data1[1:3, c("city", "age")] <- data2[1:3, c("city", "age")]
```

Results:

```
> data1
    employee salary  startdate city age
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01    1   1
2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25    2   3
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14    3   4
> class(data1[,4])
[1] "integer"
```

Can someone explain me why factors are turned to integer, and why the following works?

```
data1[, c("city", "age")] <- data2[1:3, c("city", "age")]

> data1
    employee salary  startdate  city age
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01 city1   1
2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25 city2   3
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14 city3   4
```

Is there a way to avoid this? I want to avoid using (bind functions).

Comment: It is better to work with `character` class instead of `factor` and this can be done by using the option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `read.table/read.csv` or in the `data.frame` call.  The factor levels are stored as integers, so it is possible to get coerced to the integer class.

Comment: I know that this problem can be avoided when using characters instead factors, but I would like to keep original column class and avoid situation described above.

Comment: The class of the `data1$city` is not the same as the `data2$city`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to create two variables in 'data1' from 'data2' columns, we can directly create it instead of creating new variables as `NA` and then replace the values with the corresponding columns in 'data2'.  (I am not specifying 1:3 for the row index as the `nrow` of data1 is 3).

```
 data1[c('city', 'age')] <- data2[1:3, c("city", "age")]
 data1
 #    employee salary  startdate  city age
 #1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01 city1   1
 #2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25 city2   3
 #3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14 city3   4

 data1$city
 #[1] city1 city2 city3
 #Levels: city1 city2 city3
```

But, if we are creating two variables as `NA`

```
 data1$city <- NA
 data1$age <- NA
```

the `class` of 'city' in both the datasets are not the same

```
 class(data1$city)
 #[1] "logical"

  class(data2$city)
 #[1] "factor"
```

So, this may result in coercing the `factor` class to `numeric` as the storage mode of `factor` is `numeric`..

```
 mode(data2$city)
 #[1] "numeric"
```

One option if we want to create the variables first in 'data1' and then replace is to create the variable 'city' as `factor` with levels as unique elements in `city`

```
 data1$city <- factor(NA, levels=unique(city))
 data1[, c("city", "age")] <- data2[1:3, c("city", "age")]
 data1$city
 #[1] city1 city2 city3 
 #Levels: city1 city2 city3
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun for clarification. I first need to create new columns in 'data1', because it not necessarily is the case that I populated whole column with data from 'data2'. So it could be that 'data1$city' will contain 'NA'. The second solution with defining the class for data1 new columns works.